# Adding Chrome Extension - BeautifulSoup - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I used this to add an extension with Selenium
Now I moved to working with Beautiful soup, and Im looking for a way to scrape via beautiful soup while having an extension on.
How can I do that in beautiful soup?

```
import selenium
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

executable_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\adguard.crx')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup has no interaction with your browser. BeautifulSoup is strictly used to parse html.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you did is correct... now you have to fetch the page and make a soup out it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# [...]
with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options) as driver:
   src_page = driver.page_source
   soup = BeautifulSoup(src_page, 'lxml')
   # scrape the soup
```

I strongly do NOT recommend  to parse online but save the source page so that you can **scrape** offline...

```
   # from above
   with open('my_file_for_offline_scraping', 'w') as fd:
       fd.write(src_page)

with open('my_file_for_offline_scraping', 'r') as fd:
   soup = BeautifulSoup(fd.read(), 'lxml')
   # scrape-scrape
```